# TypeError: self.parent.parent.parent.context is not a function Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular

I've created this function to save my `taches`

```js
sauverTache(tache:Tache){

    this.editionEnCours = true;
    tache.estReelle = true;

    this.sauverTache.emit(tache.id);
}
```

I call my function in the template like this

```html
<div class="sbold tr" *ngFor="let tache of etapes.P0.taches, let i=index" [class.hidden]="!afficheTaches" >
                                        <td  align="right">{{tache.typeTache}}&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div>
                                               <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="etapes.P0.taches[i].dateTache"  showAnim="slideDown" [class.hidden]="!editP0[i]" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" placeholder="jj/mm/aaaa"></p-calendar>
                                                <div class="btn btn-circle btn-default font-yellow-saffron" *ngIf="!editP0[i]" (click)="editP0[i]=!editP0[i]">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-pencil "> </i>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="btn btn-circle btn-default font-green-jungle" *ngIf="editP0[i]" (click)="editP0[i]=!editP0[i]; sauverTache(etapes.P0.taches[i]);">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-check "> </i>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="btn btn-circle btn-default font-red" *ngIf="editP0[i]" (click)="editP0[i]=!editP0[i]; reset();">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-remove "> </i>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
  </div>
```

and I got this error

```js
TypeError: self.parent.parent.parent.context.sauverTache is not a function
```

Answer (score 5):

The way how to get to argument emitted by the *event* is just via keyword **`$event`**:

```
//(click)="edit=!edit; sauverTache(myTache);"
(click)="edit=!edit; sauverTache($event);"
```

In case you need the parameter coming from some iterated array, you can pass it as well

```
<div *ngFor="let myTache of Taches">
  ...
  <div class="btn btn-circle btn-default font-green-jungle" 
     *ngIf="edit" (click)="edit=!edit; sauverTache(myTache);">
   <i class="fa fa-check "> </i>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

And in case that we need some setting from our component class, we can also

```
class MyComponent {
    public myTache: number;
    ngOnInit() {
       this.myTache = 1;
    }
}
```

and now we can ask for that to be passed as in original snippet

```
(click)="edit=!edit; sauverTache(myTache);
```

Simply, we either need to have **`myTache`** to be a local variable (usually part of ngFor) or a property on our component. If we need to consume events arguments - we should ask for $event

EXTEND

The biggest issue is inside of the sauverTache, where we want to emit some data. That must be done with a help of EventEmitter:

```
  sauverTacheObservable = new EventEmitter();

  sauverTache(tache: Tache){

    this.editionEnCours = true;
    tache.estReelle = true;

    // this is self calling.. and causing problem...
    // this method does not have method emit
    //this.sauverTache.emit(tache.id);

    // but now, we call proper emitter
    this.sauverTacheObservable.emit(tache.id);
    console.log(tache.id);
  }
```

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yvboj6iDi8hZcdJKiYMY?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how can I specify to the function which tache I want to save?

Comment: I'm exactly working with a *ngFor="let myTache of Taches", and Taches= Array<Tache>; defined in my component. I can't see how can I use  $event in this case?

Comment: I found your issue, extended answer, created plunker and added more details. We need to call Emitter not the function itself

Comment: Yes.. and there you can consume fired parameter with `sauverTache)="sauverPlannings($event)"` and in the code of `sauverPlannings(myTacheId)` you will consume that id... hope it helps a bit ;)

Comment: Thanks for the plunker. But I'm using my component in an other template, like this `<my-component
                                   [projet]="projet"
                                   (sauverTache)="sauverPlannings()">

                            </my-component> `. Should I replace sauverPlannings() by sauverPlannings($event)?

Comment: And how can I consume that id?

Comment: There is updated plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/zTtmdonwk0AFmHVowqGk?p=preview. MyComp is component - inner one, which has @Output property... App is subscribing to it with `(sauverTacheObservable)="mySubscrier($event)"` that should now give you clear picture

Comment: Thank you for your collaboration. But I still have the same error :/

Comment: Please, take your time, and observe my example. It shows the whole process.. declare output as emitter... consume it by passing $event... if you will understand that simple example... you will make it! I am sure! Good luck sir ;)

Comment: +1 for "Simply, we either need to have myTache to be a local variable (usually part of ngFor) or a property on our componet", thanks :)